# Marketing equipment and the fine line between words describing condition

Tags: semantics, marketing

Hi Stackeschange folks!

I'm a business owner working on my marketing, and have encountered a problem of semantics regarding the condition of the equipment we sell. Please pardon the long introduction to the english related question:

We sell used laboratory equipment and we take the approach of being accurate and honest in our descriptions. We're trying to avoid overselling our work in an industry where I feel there is a lot of misrepresentation of the abilities of dealers.

However, our company has some strong technical staff, and we do some excellent work on certain types of equipment and we want to make sure that we don't undersell ourselves if possible.

The problem we have run in to is that on one of the most popular used lab equipment marketplaces, eBay, the conditions offered to us to describe our equipment fall short of being precise enough. Allow me to describe them:

**Used:** The item was previously used. The item may have some signs of cosmetic wear, but it is fully operational and functions as intended. This item may be a floor model or store return that has been used. See the seller’s listing for full details and a description of any imperfections.

**Seller Refurbished:** The item was restored to working order by the eBay seller or a third party not approved by the manufacturer. This means the item has been inspected, cleaned, and repaired to full working order and is in excellent condition. This item may or may not be in original packaging. See the seller’s listing for full details.

Now, the problem we run in to here is that the "Seller Refurbished" definition requires the instrument to be in excellent condition. Despite doing some cosmetic work on our instruments, often times our best items that have undergone significant mechanical repair and service and are superior than an unserviced piece of used equipment are not in truly excellent condition. The cost/time can often be too much to be justified.

We do emphasize descriptive and precise product descriptions, but when your customer is busy, it is handy to have a short definition of the condition of your product.

---

So now the questions regarding language arise. The word "reconditioned" has been pitched as a one-word definition for what we do. But I thought I would pose this question to a community of language nerds. Here are a few questions I would enjoy hearing the answer to:

What does "refurbished" mean to you, especially concerning capital equipment?
What does "reconditioned" mean to you?
How would you differentiate between "refurbished" and "reconditioned"?
Do you have an alternative one-word or two-word definition for what we do?

Sincerely,

I like honest business

Comment: Please look up 'precising definition' in Wikipedia. Different definitions for the same word is the norm in English. If there are _legal definitions_, then when there is liability, these trump even the most frequently used / understood ones in common parlance.

Comment: tldr; Is this an ad in itself?

Comment: Legalities aren't really a concern in this situation - it's not regulated in any way.